# Change maven profile from within project

Tags: java, maven

I want to change maven project's active profile from within the maven project.

The java project has 3 classes having main methods and they are executed one by one, All of these require different set of dependencies.

I would like to run these classes with different maven profiles.

For example my project project1 is a maven project and is getting invoked by mvn clean package spring-boot:run command.

When the control comes to the project1 it executes the java classes one by one.

My requirement is that when ClassA is run it should change the current maven profile to profile1 (recompiling the same project is ok, performance is not priority). Similarly when ClassB gets invoked it should change the current maven profile to Profile2.
(Note these classes are dynamically picked from directory using reflection and only the class will know what profile it supports)

Is there any way maven allows this at runtime.
If not what is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: If you have different classes which need different set of dependencies you have to make three different modules / applications of them. You are mixing build and run time ... `My requirement is that when ClassA is run it should change the current maven profile to profile1` That's simply not possilbe. 
You have to make separate modules of it... for each modules you can give different dependencies...

Comment: is it possible in Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

maven profiles are not designed for such tasks, what you are actually need to do is to setup different executions for each class:

```xml
...
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>run-clsa</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>ClassA</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>run-clsb</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>ClassB</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
...
```

and run that in following way:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run@run-clsa
```

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run@run-clsb
```

Comment: This is not possible because classes are added dynamically and only the class will know which execution is supported. Also the project is invoked by another application so it can not be invoked multiple times. All the changes needs to be done from within the application itself. 

Essentially caller should not be aware of the presence of these classes, once the control is passed to the project, it is freed.

Comment: Another option can be classes have execution defined and if it can check what the current execution is, then all classes belonging to one execution can be called in a group

Comment: @AmitMahajan In that case you are doing something wrong: maven is a build system: it get source code as input and produces artifacts, end of story. And maven plugins are designed to support build process but not to manage applications. You are actually has an option to run something like `mvn clean package spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.main-class=ClassA` or even create profiles where you may define `spring-boot.run.main-class` in `properties` (or define your own property and use it as placeholder in `<mainClass>${myCoolProperty}</mainClass>`)

Comment: but I strongly suggest to avoid such use cases in maven - that is not it's responsibility.

Comment: I am building a framework for usecases (tests), once it is invoked it will execute usecases ony by one, the usecases needs specific dependencies, for this I was thinking to group these usecase specific dependies to one profile. What can be the alternative in this case.